# Unable to catch Exception when it is thrown from that

Tags: java, exception

I have done something like this:

```
try {
    client = new Client(this, "192.168.0.108", 5204);
}catch(ConnectException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

IDE says:

> Unreachable catch block for ConnectException. This exception is never
>   thrown from the try statement body

but when I run it and force-close the program (GUI window where it is running) it generates Exception from that line of code (Client object).

I know that in -try- block I havent anything what can formally throwns Exception, but in real Exception is thrown from that block.

How to catch that ConnectException?

Stack trace:
https://prnt.sc/q9hzdp

Comment: Can you show your stack trace?

Comment: Well it is not a ConnectException then... or at least not the one you are importing

Comment: The one you are importing here is a checked exception... which means it either needs to be handled internally (with try catch) or placed on the method declaration with throws.. which would force you to handle it in your supplied code... check the import

Comment: Stack trace: https://prnt.sc/q9hzdp I am sure I am importing the right Exception

Comment: You are either not importing right `Client` or right `ConnectException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IDE is complaining because the exception you're trying to catch is already being caught in the constructor of Client.

Taken from [Client.java](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/java/libraries/net/src/processing/net/Client.java) source:

```
public Client(PApplet parent, String host, int port) {
    ...
    try {
      socket = new Socket(this.host, this.port);
      ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      ...
    }
}
```

ConnectException extends IOException, so the exception is already being caught by the Processing library. Since the exception is not rethrown, it won't propagate up to your custom try-catch and makes it redundant.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It make sense now. So I am not able to catch it in any way?

Comment: Not while the Client constructor is catching it. If it's very important to catch, you can remove the Client's try-catch from the Processing library source and build a custom version of the library, or use Javassist or CGLIB to modify Client's bytecode and add the custom logic you want in your catch. Modifying the source will be more performant; Javassist or CGLIB will probably be easier.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth when I ran into this problem, I simply checked the String of the stack trace for the specific exception I needed to intercept, then I had a method handle it. However, I'm not coding for "mission-critical" apps, I'm just a hobby programmer. I think the first answer with the second comment where Travieso references the use of Javassist and GLIB is the best answer, but in my case, the learning curve to implement that solution was too steep.

Here is an example of how I handled this problem:

```
catch (SQLException | IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    if (e.toString().contains("InvalidClassException")) {
        invalidClassExceptionHandler();
    }
    else {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```